# Avoid Deadlock on concurrent insert

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-8.0, concurrency

I am trying to avoid a future problem.

Table has 2 fields:

`id -> bigint Primary key`

`hash -> varchar(65) unique key`

there will be concurrent inserts into the table for hash.
I need the last insert id

So question:
`INSERT INTO table (hash) VALUES(blah) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)`
Generate deadlocks if there are 30-50 threads, there is a high chance that these threads will try to insert the same blah?

OR do I need to do:
`SELECT id FROM table WHERE hash=blah`
if exists GREAT

if doesnt exist:

`INSERT IGNORE INTO table (hash) VALUES(blah);`

`SELECT id FROM table WHERE hash=blah`

Edit:
Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `hash_list` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hash` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `hash_UNIQUE` (`hash`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

I have no control over the hash. All I need is to store the hash ONCE and get the id many times so it can be used elsewhere in the application. Without deadlocks. This way I get storage savings that will become significant over time.

Edit 2:
I've marked danblack's answer as accepted because of the ROW_COUNT() suggestion. But Rick James has valid points as well. Both answers are great!

Edit 3: interestingly with 100+ plus I am seeing 0 deadlocks.

Comment: `id` looks by the `update` part of your `insert` to be the secondary field and hash is the pk? Is `varchar(65)` the smallest the hash can be? consider `binary(X)` and remove any hex, base64 etc encoding on it as you insert it. With `hash` as the pk do you need `id`? Do you really want to update the `id` on duplicate? or ignore?

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; so we can see what the system is working with.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I added the table definition. Thanks!

Comment: @danblack this table is not set in stone, its my interpretation of what I need. I need to store the hash, that I have no control over, once and get the id of the row where it is stored, so the application can use that id elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to summarize the problem, input is a hash that needs to be stored. And the auto_increment of that ID is needed.

You've done the right thing and made `hash` a `unique key`.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO hash_list (hash) VALUES(?);
```

Is correct. In the application API or SQL (`ROW_COUNT()`) you will get a rows affected. 0 indicates that it already existed.

If it already existed you'll need to fetch the `id` with:

```
SELECT id FROM hash_list WHERE hash=?
```

If the `ROW_COUNT()` is 1, then the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` (both of which are in the application API so a separate query isn't needed) is the `id` you need.

Recommend using a binary type for the hash, as by its name it isn't going to be utf8mb4.

Depending if you are needing to insert more or retrieve the hash by id more, you can make `hash` the primary key and `id` a unique `AUTO_INCREMENT` key as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `hash_list` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hash` varbinary(45),
  PRIMARY KEY (`hash`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

The above queries will work regardless of the table structure provided `hash` is a unique key or a primary key. The `AUTO_INCREMENT` column needs to be indexed.

ref: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d9c26063687b6a8bc780397964a51b42)

Comment: Well damn!! I didn't even think of the ROW_COUNT(), Thanks for that!! may i ask: why varbinary? is varbinary faster over varchar?

Comment: varbinary / binary has no character set. So there's storage overhead or implicit conversions associated with it. Depending on the hash, it can have a fixed width. You can remove the encoding (hex/base64) of it too and store it in its minimal binary. You can also use the virtual generated column in the table to expose a text form if you want.

Answer (score 1):

What client language are you using?  There may be a way to get the `id` *without* touching the table again.  It is called `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in some APIs.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table (hash) VALUES(blah);
reach for last_insert_id in the API.  Or possibly
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Be aware that `IGNORE` and IODKU will "burn" an id if it does not actually insert.  (Since you are using `BIGINT`, you won't run out of ids.)

Also, consciously decide what "transaction" to include the INSERT in.  Note that your 2-step (SELECT; if then INSERT) *must* be in a transaction and the `SELECT` *must* have `FOR UPDATE`.  Hence, for a *single* insert, IODKU is better.

If this is a "normalization" table, and you expect to bulk-load it, see this for more tips:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization  The advice there avoids burning ids, is fast, etc.

If that hash is hex, you may as well declare it `CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_general_ci`.

Comment: I am using PHP. I indeed have LAST_INSERT_ID and ROW_COUNT(). The burn really doesnt matter, bigint should take care of it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will test both your and @danblack answer and see which is faster. For now its time for bed:)

Comment: @AndriyLysak - Be aware that you cannot avoid all deadlocks.  So, check for errors and be ready to replay the transaction if it deadlocks.  How many CPU cores do you have?  There is a higher risk of deadlocks _and poor latency_ if the number of threads exceeds cores.

Comment: 2 cores... 50+ threads, will put it in a try catch and see what happens:) Thanks

Comment: @AndriyLysak - Is this a benchmark?  Or do you really have that many users connecting concurrently?

Comment: its not a benchmark, depending on how much data there is to process per day, there will be between 10-50 threads. Depending if these IODKU queries slow it down, might need more threads to keep up with the volume.

Comment: @AndriyLysak - Instead of that, develop a way to gather, say, 100 or on minute's worth of items before putting them into the table.  Batching cay run 10 times as fast.

Comment: will see if i can do that, thanks!!

Comment: So batching is the correct approach but requires a lot of RAM which limits me. This is no longer an IODKU and deadlock issue so wont clog up the comments. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @AndriyLysak - Collection a hundred items should not take much RAM, should it?

Comment: Thats true, you are correct batching is faster!